# How do I combine records with the same columns and extend the time range?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I combine records with the same columns and extend the time range?

Example tables:

```
  id | date_from | date_to | param1 | param2  |     |   
 ----|-----------|---------|--------|---------|-----|--- 
   1 |      2009 |    2010 | 'A'    |         | 'A' |   
   1 |      2009 |    2010 | 'A'    | 'A'     |     |   
   1 |      2011 |    2012 | 'A'    | 'A'     |     |   
   1 |      2013 |    2014 | 'B'    | 'B'     |     |   
   1 |      2015 |    2016 | 'A'    | 'A'     |     |   
   1 |      2017 |    2018 | 'A'    | 'A'     |     |
```

It must be so:

```
  id | date_from | date_to | param1 | param2  
 ----|-----------|---------|--------|--------- 
   1 |      2009 |    2012 | 'A'    | 'A'     
   1 |      2013 |    2014 | 'B'    | 'B'     
   1 |      2015 |    2018 | 'A'    | 'A'
```

I tried using window functions, but I don't know what to do next

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition BY id ORDER BY date_from ASC) AS step, 
       dense_rank() OVER(partition BY id ORDER BY param1, param2) AS rnk, 
       * 
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) dense_rank solution:

```
with tbl_with_group as (
    select 
        t.*,
        dense_rank() over(partition BY id order BY date_from) - dense_rank() OVER(partition BY id, param1, param2 order by date_from) group_number
    from 
        table t
)
select 
    id, min(date_from), max(date_to), param1, param2
from 
    tbl_with_group 
group by 
    id, group_number, param1, param2
```

2) lag solution:

```
with tbl_with_delimiter as (
    select 
        t.*,
        case when 
            lag(param1) over(partition by id order by date_from) = param1 and
            lag(param2) over(partition by id order by date_from) = param2
        then 0 else 1 end is_new_group_start
    from 
        table t
),
tbl_with_group as (
    select 
        t.*,
        sum(is_new_group_start) over(partition by id order by date_from) group_number
    from 
        tbl_with_delimiter t
)
select 
    id, min(date_from), max(date_to), param1, param2
from 
    tbl_with_group 
group by 
    id, group_number, param1, param2
order by
    id, group_number
```

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible to replace "dense_rank () over (Partition by id ORDER BY date_from) - dense_rank () over (Partition by id, param1, param2 ORDER BY date_from)" with lag ()?

Comment: @Sergey, add solution with lag

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()` & find the grouping & do aggregation :

```
select id, min(date_from) as date_from, max(date_to) as date_to, param1, param2 
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when (date_from - prev_to) = 1 then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by id, param1, param2 order by date_from) as grp
      from (select t.*, 
                   lag(date_to) over (partition by id, param1, param2 order by date_from) as prev_to
            from table t
           ) t
     ) t
group by id,  param1, param2, grp
order by id, date_from;
```

Answer (score 0):

Absent any other explanation, I have to assume that the "from" and "to" dates could be arbitrarily overlapping or having gaps.  To solve this problem, I recommend expanding the data for each individual year and then treating this as a simple gaps-and-islands problem:

```
select id, min(date_from), max(date_to), param1, param2
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by param1, param2 order by gs.y) as seqnum
      from t cross join lateral
           generate_series(t.date_from, t.date_to, 1) as gs(y)
     ) t
group by id, (y - seqnum), param1, param2;
```